# insert hash in url to give starting reference to :target pseudo class based navigation?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to build a horizontal accordion nav menu using CSS3, anchor tags and :target pseudo class. I almost have it worked out. I just need some way to set the top level list items to appear on page load.

jsfiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/4jpowell/nzAsr/4/

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.nav {
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
.menu, .menu * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.menu a:link {
    color: #9D0C0C; 
}
.menu a {
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 0.25em;
    border: 2px solid #9D0C0C;
    position: static;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}
/*top level link is selected*/
/*hide other top level links*/
.menu > li:not(:target) {
    display: none;
}
/*expand*/
    li:target .subnav {
    display: block;
}
/*default*/
.menu > li {
    display: block;
}
.subnav {
    display: none;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}
/*level 2 nav links*/
    li ul li {
    float: left;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="nav">
        <ul class="menu">
            <li id="about">
                <a href="#about">About</a>
                <ul class="subnav">
                    <li><a href="#">Mission</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Press</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="events">
                <a href="#events">Events</a>
                <ul class="subnav">
                    <li><a href="#">Upcoming Events</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Past Events</a></li><li><a href="#">Press</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="programs">
                <a href="#programs">Programs</a>
                <ul class="subnav">
                    <li><a href="#">Festival</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Performance</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Public Arts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Oral History</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
<script>
    $(window).trigger('hashchange');
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using jQuery Accordian UI.
[Link here](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/)

Comment: I need the menu sublinks to expand horizontally and replace the unselected top level menu links. There are a few posts on hacking the jquery accordion UI to display top level menu items horizontally with vertical submenu dropdowns but Accordion UI doesn't seem suited to the level of modification that would be needed to achieve what I'm attempting.

Comment: I updated the above code based on more recent efforts, but still haven't figure out how to display the menu when the page loads since the styles default to `display:none` to make the menu function.